# why do these calendar javascripts hide select, applet, and iframe tags for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, calendar

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with an older site than I'm supporting. The problem is that in IE8, a SELECT tag is being hidden. Turns out it is due to an older version of a calendar.js which is applying `visibility:hidden` style to not only SELECT Tags, but also applets and iframes.

I'm rusty on my javascript and details of older browser quirks, but the thing I find odd is that it's hiding these tags when they are unrelated to the calendar. In the page with the problem, this select tag that's being hidden is in a div above the calendar objects, although they are in the same form.

Is this a problem with an earlier version of IE? Would it be 'safe' to put in an if to check the version of IE, and not apply these styles for version 8 and later?

Here's the function from calendar.js:

```
Calendar.prototype.hideShowCovered = function () {
  if (!Calendar.is_ie && !Calendar.is_opera)
    return;
  function getVisib(obj){
    var value = obj.style.visibility;
    if (!value) {
      if (document.defaultView && typeof (document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) == "function") { // Gecko, W3C
        if (!Calendar.is_khtml)
          value = document.defaultView.
            getComputedStyle(obj, "").getPropertyValue("visibility");
        else
          value = '';
      } else if (obj.currentStyle) { // IE
        value = obj.currentStyle.visibility;
      } else
        value = '';
    }
    return value;
  };

  var tags = new Array("applet", "iframe", "select");
  var el = this.element;

  var p = Calendar.getAbsolutePos(el);
  var EX1 = p.x;
  var EX2 = el.offsetWidth + EX1;
  var EY1 = p.y;
  var EY2 = el.offsetHeight + EY1;

  for (var k = tags.length; k > 0; ) {
    var ar = document.getElementsByTagName(tags[--k]);
    var cc = null;

    for (var i = ar.length; i > 0;) {
      cc = ar[--i];

      p = Calendar.getAbsolutePos(cc);
      var CX1 = p.x;
      var CX2 = cc.offsetWidth + CX1;
      var CY1 = p.y;
      var CY2 = cc.offsetHeight + CY1;

      if (this.hidden || (CX1 > EX2) || (CX2 < EX1) || (CY1 > EY2) || (CY2 < EY1)) {
        if (!cc.__msh_save_visibility) {
          cc.__msh_save_visibility = getVisib(cc);
        }
        cc.style.visibility = cc.__msh_save_visibility;
      } else {
        if (!cc.__msh_save_visibility) {
          cc.__msh_save_visibility = getVisib(cc);
        }
        cc.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Those objects are/were always at the top of the Z order, meaning that they would show up on top of your calendar if it tried to appear on top of them.

It's no longer true for `select` in any modern browser, and (you'd need to test it but) I suspect the same thing is true for `iframe`. They certainly don't have this problem in IE8.

`applet`, on the other hand, almost certainly still has the problem, being a heavyweight window embedded into the page.  Flash in heavyweight-window mode will have the same problem too.