# Form fields become invisible when Calendar icon selected - Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calendar, visibility

I've been struggling with this form for a while now: http://www.thebeardmore.com/booking-mask/

I'm using Google Chrome for debugging.

When I click the 'Calendar' icon, the dates box appears, covering the input fields (nights/adults/children) underneath.

However, this also makes these fields completely invisible (visibility:hidden) from then on.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the script hides any element (by setting `visibility: hidden`) which the calendar cover. This was, I believe, because of rendering problems in IE6. However, it causes problems in [Chrome](http://lists.koha-community.org/pipermail/koha-patches/2011-February/013880.html) and [IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873855/why-do-these-calendar-javascripts-hide-select-applet-and-iframe-tags-for-ie), so it's worth probably disabling this behavior.

A couple of ways to do it:

1) Set `visibility: visible` inline:

`<select id="nights" name="Length" style="visibility: visible">`

2) (Preferable) Override the Calendar's `hideShowCovered` method:

```
// At the top of your script
Calendar.prototype.hideShowCovered = function() {};
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Many thanks for taking a look. Can you confirm where the 2nd piece of code is to appear? Is it appearing at the top of 'calendar.js'? Many thanks

Comment: at the top of your <script> tag should be fine (e.g. above `Calendar.setup`)

Comment: I used the first method which works perfectly. I have to thank you once again for taking the time to look - you're the best!!